# Show sql table data in datagridview with 3 parameters

Tags: c#

I'm building an application where I have to filter data in sql table with 3 parameters. I have allready done that I filter data between 2 datetimepickers, but I want also the insert 3rd parameter which will filter between the people ID so it will show only selected person by his ID.
I have done SQL tables and put relations between them so they are connected together.

I will show you my tables and relations between them, code which I allready put in for the date time pickers, and the picture what I want to inplant inside the filter.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Zelvice
{
public partial class Pregled : Form
{
  string ConnectionString = @"Data source = .\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= |DataDirectory|\App_Data\Zelvice1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    public Pregled()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Pregled_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void PrikaziBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OdDTP.Value > DoDTP.Value)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have picked wrong date interval!");
        }

        else
        {
             string query = "select * from Kartice where Datum_Izvedbe BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDate", OdDTP.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDate", DoDTP.Value);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            connection.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "attendance");
            PregledDGV.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
    }    
}
```

The picture of my tables and relations
[Sql tables](http://prntscr.com/2isa9c)

this is my combobox with people/users which I want to insert in above datagridview filter
[People/Users](http://prntscr.com/2iscoy)

Comment: And what's your question / problem ?

Comment: How to add the combobox option into datagridview filter... select* from....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
string query = "select * from Kartice where ID=" + combobox.SelectedItem.ID.ToString() + " AND Datum_Izvedbe BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate";
```

Comment: I cant put combobox.selestedItem.ID.ToString() cuz I get error:the mulit-part identifier "system.data.datarowView" could not be bound... in the section
da.fill(ds, "attendance":)

Comment: You have to change ID to whatever your actual ID is for the objects bound to the combo box.

Comment: I did but still get some error.

I have written like this string query = "select * from Kartice where Upor_ID= " + IzborUporCombo.SelectedItem.Upor_ID.ToString() + " AND Datum_Izvedbe BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate";

and got this error:
Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Upor_ID' and no extension method 'Upor_ID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Matjaž\Zelvice\Zelvice\Pregled.cs 38 106 Zelvice

Comment: What do you have bound to your combobox then?

Comment: I have connected the other table Users on combobox connected, and that's the problem :( now I figuerd out, but how can I set now that will be showed in datagrid only the ID I selected in combo and later also filterd with datetimepickers